# Play video in loop +AVQueuePlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, loops, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I had used this video to play without jerk.But how to play the **secondVideoItem** in loop..That is after video get play i want to add this video to 10-15time.
Only **secondVideoItem** not **firstVideoItem**.

```
NSString *secondVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSString *firstVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2" ofType:@"mp4"];


    AVPlayerItem *firstVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:firstVideoPath]];
    AVPlayerItem *secondVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:secondVideoPath]];

   AVQueuePlayer* queuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVideoItem, secondVideoItem,nil]];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:queuePlayer];
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay;
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

    [queuePlayer play];
```

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After played the second item this will call a notification and rewind the video so it will start playing again...

```
queuePlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone; 

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(itemPlayEnded:)
                                               name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                             object:[queuePlayer currentItem]];

- (void)itemPlayEnded:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
 k++;
 if(k<10-15 times)
 {
  AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
  [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I play the both the video.I want to play only the second video to 10-15time.I dont want to start it all again.I just want to start the 2nd video .IS it possible.if yes then please guide me

Comment: yes by above code it should rewind or replay ur secondItem.n it should start playing again..try if its doing it...

Comment: I had tried it..But it play both :- video1 and video2 files.I want to play only video2 in loop

Comment: @shweta after watching this it doesn't seem 'not working code' answer you posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765990/avqueueplayer-loop-last-item-in-a-queue-and-eliminate-hiccup-or-loop-last-sec

Comment: is there any way that instead of taking new layer.We can repeat only the 2nd item of array to play loop.As it gives the minor jerk by doing in this way..

Comment: when 1video file end  and then 2nd start the is delay of some milisecond,which show the jerk.

Comment: may be because you are starting it from very beginning 0th sec frame so what you can try is [queuePlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1,1)]; another thing if i am right,you are adding layer again while making new queue, you can reuse old layer without addSubLayer-ing it again...